# UILabel in iOS 10, make text font

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm having trouble having text fit in my UILabel using iOS 10 if the text exceeds the size of the width/height constraints of my label.

This is the size inspector in the Storyboard for the UILabel:

[image]

I want to UILabel itself to always have a fixed width and height as it currently has in the Storyboard. I just want the text to word wrap/change font size and do whatever it has to, to fit the confines of that width/height specification. I've tried the following on the UILabel:

`adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth`
`numberOfLines = 0`

I can't seem to get the right configuration.

Comment: It sounds like you've tried the right thing - adjustsFontSizeToWidth - but maybe if you included your code something might stick out. Also, check that you have the IBOutlet created correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must set [`minimumScaleFactor`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uilabel/1620544-minimumscalefactor) less than 1 and `numberOfLines` to 1 or greater for `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` to have an effect.

### Swift Code

```
label.numberOfLines = 1
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
```

### Interface Builder

[image]